# Can not override scope option in auth0-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auth0, pkce

I'm using the `"@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.5.0"` package for `pkce` authentication.
I tried to set the `scope`, but it seems it didn't work:

```js
// method1 which I've tried
   <Auth0Provider
      domain={urls().oauth}
      clientId={apiConstants.clientId}
      redirectUri={urls().redirect}
      scope="read"
    >
          <AppRouter />
    </Auth0Provider>
```

```js
// method2 in the loginWithRedirect
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

function Auth0LoginButton() {
  const { isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();

  return isAuthenticated ? null : (
    <button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect({ scope: "read" })}>
      Log in via Auth0 PKCE
    </button>
  );
}

export default Auth0LoginButton;
```

Also tried both method together, but no progress. The output will be always `scope=openid profile email read`.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed here in the `auth0-react`'s github, [here is the maintainer answers](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react/issues/242):

Any scope you set in the Provider or when calling `loginWithRedirect` will be appended to the configured default scopes, which are set to `openid profile email` by default.

As documented in [Advanced Options](https://auth0.github.io/auth0-react/interfaces/auth0_provider.auth0provideroptions.html#advancedoptions), If you do not want those `default scope`, you can override them by using:

```
<Auth0Provider  advancedOptions={{defaultScope: ''}}>...</Auth0Provider>
```

Keep in mind, `openid` will always be added, regardless of what you use as defaultScope, because it is [required](https://auth0.com/docs/scopes/openid-connect-scopes).